# UISearchDisplayController jumps to the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've seen the question at some places, but not one helped me. Been searching for a while now, so I'll just ask it here.

I have a problem with `UISearchDisplayController`. The `tableView` this is working on doesn't take the whole screen, only the right side:

[image: The tableView]

When I tap the searchBar on top it jumps to this:

[image: The tapped searchBar]

And when I actually search, this is what I get:

[image: The result]

I've tried several 'solutions' like:

```
 - (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController
 *)controller {
     controller.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(300, 20, 744, 44); 
 }

 - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carListDropbox.frame.size.width,
 self.carListDropbox.frame.size.height); 
 }

 - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     tableView.frame = self.carListDropbox.frame; 
 }
```

They don't seem to help AT ALL. Is there any other way I can lock the searchBar (and UISearchDisplayController) into a view?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to make search controllers work in this way and had many problems with the search results tableview not being in the right position and the search bar not being in the right position either. It seems apple's default design for these animates it to the top and does not really give you much information or control over how this is done.

While I'm not sure if there is a way to lock the searchBar into the view(and get the searchResultsTableView to position properly all the time) because there may be a way to do this that I don't know, but I think it is not worth the trouble.

Instead, I'd recommend making your own search bar and searchresultstableview which you can control, animate and position however you'd like whenever you want to, no headache. Make your searchresultstableview hidden until they enter the text field or start typing in it, then show it as desired. If you want it to look the same you'll have to draw your own search icon and search bar which isn't too difficult with UIBezierPath, or you can add your own images.

Comment: Argh, not the answer I was looking for but you might be right. I'll just wait a couple more days for others, but if nobody can help me, I will mark this one the Answer. Thx!